# Throw Exception for unsupported characters

Tags: java, exception

I have user input

```
private Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = inn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

and i need to throw IllegalCharacterException(own exception, created this class already) for not desired input (all numerals and symbols and maybe even other languages)I need only english letters. How can i do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.matches(String regex)` with regular expressions. E.g.

```java
private Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = inn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
if(input.matches("[a-z]*")) {
  // Do some stuff
}
```

The Regular expression `[a-z]*` matches any character from a to z (lowercase), without any numbers, symbols or spaces.

Comment: Would be nice if you mark then the answer as solution. :)

Comment: done it already)